# PHP array saying nonexistance

Tags: php, arrays

I searched through the site, with keywords like "PHP array error" and "data not being found by PHP" but I can't find an answer that fits what I need.
I am making a really basic password protected site, with text files. I will include code below, but the error that comes up is;

```
Array ( ) count of banned = 1
Notice: Undefined index: banned[0] in C:\xampp\htdocs\dns\domains\bank\login.php on line 17
```

But I am unsure why. The code is in php, and is below.

```
<?php
//variables
$user = $_POST["user"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];
$banned = array("admin");
$users = array("admin");
$c = count($users);
$users = print_r(glob("../users/*.txt"));
$r = count($banned);
$k = $r - 1;
echo "count of banned = $r";
$loop = 0;
$isbanned = true;

//check if banned
while ($loop <= $k) {
if ($GLOBALS["user"] == $GLOBALS["banned"][$loop]) {
echo "sorry but this account is banned from this site!";
$GLOBALS["isbanned"] = true;
} 
$loop = $loop + 1;
}
if ($isbanned == false) {
//if you are not banned, check if you are even a proper user with password!
$loop = 0;
while ($loop <= $r) {
if ($GLOBALS["user"] == $GLOBALS["users[$loop]"]) {
$person = print_r(file($GLOBALS["user"] . ".txt"));
if ($GLOBALS["pass"] == $GLOBALS["person[0]"]) {
header('location /welcome.php');
die();
}
} 
$loop = $loop + 1;
}
}
?>
```

and below is the contents of my folder. The index.php is only a basic form, which works.

```
-index.php
-login.php
-Users
|-user.txt
```

and sorry for all the snip its, but the contents of each .txt file are as they follow;

```
1234
2000
```

The first line is the password, the second for a later project, is the cash.
If there is any other information you wish to see I will try to get it.
Thank you for reviewing my question.
--------------------------------------Part 2------------------------------------
Thank you Barmar for answering the 1st question.
After fixing the code, if not correct on here sorry, the system still wont fetch the content of the files to the array, so it still wont work as a login system. I know I should make this a new question, but it seemed to fit better like this. Thank you for reviewing my questions.

Comment: Globals, globals, globals....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$GLOBALS["banned[$loop]"]` should be `$GLOBALS["banned"][$loop]`. The index is not part of the variable name. The variable contains an array, and then you need to index that.

But there's no need to use `$GLOBALS` at all. Your code is at the global scope, so it can access global variables normally. That line should be:

```
if ($user == $banned[$loop])
```

And if you want to access a global variable inside a function, you can use the `global` declaration:

```
global $user, $banned, $users, $is_banned;
```